# Member does not have default constructor

Tags: c++, oop, openframeworks

I am new to openFrameworks/C++ but have been using Processing/Java for some time. I am having trouble instantiating an object whose class I created in the testApp header.

It throws the error:

```
Implicit default constructor for 'testApp' must explicitly initialize the member 'currentSeq' which does not have a default constructor.
```

Here is my Sequence.h file:

```
#pragma once
#include "ofMain.h"

class Sequence{

public:
    Sequence(long _start, long _stop){
        start = _start;
        stop = _stop;
    }

    long start;
    long stop;

};
```

And this is my testApp.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "ofMain.h"
#include "sequence.h"

class testApp : public ofBaseApp{
    public:

        void setSequences();
        bool needsNewSeq();

        void setup();
        void update();
        void draw();

        void keyPressed(int key);
        void keyReleased(int key);
        void mouseMoved(int x, int y);
        void mouseDragged(int x, int y, int button);
        void mousePressed(int x, int y, int button);
        void mouseReleased(int x, int y, int button);
        void windowResized(int w, int h);
        void dragEvent(ofDragInfo dragInfo);
        void gotMessage(ofMessage msg);

        int numSequences;
        int seqIndex;
        bool isPaused;

        Sequence currentSeq;
        vector <Sequence> sequences;
        ofVideoPlayer myVideo;

};
```

The problem is the `currentSeq` variable. The vector of Sequences is fine for some reason though. According to [this](http://www.openframeworks.cc/tutorials/first%20steps/003_ooops_object_oriented_programming.html) openFrameworks tutorial I seem to be doing everything correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your parameritized constructor `Sequence(long, long)` overrides the compiler-generated default-constructor, thereby implicitly-deleting the default-constructor for `testApp`. On the line where you do:

```
Sequence currentSeq;
```

This inhibits default-construction of `testApp`, because there is no viable constructor for `currentSeq`, hence the error. To fix this, apply a default-constructor for your `Sequence` class (you should also initialize the `start` and `stop` members to 0):

```
class Sequence
{
public:
    Sequence() : start(0), stop(0)
//  ^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    { }

    Sequence(long _start, long _stop)
        : start(_start), stop(_stop) // Use member-initializer list here too
    { }

    long start;
    long stop;

};
```

Alternatively, you can provide a default-constructor for `testApp` and construct `currentSeq` like this:

```
class testApp : public ofBaseApp
{
    testApp() : currentSeq(0, 0)
    { }
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You have created a one-argument constructor for Sequence, but not a default (no-argument) constructor. Because you have created one (any) constructor, the compiler can't generate one for you.

Try adding a default constructor:

```
Sequence(){
    start = 0;
    stop = 0;
}
```

Actually, as I look at it, you also have a vector of Sequence. You're definitely going to need a default constructor, and probably a copy constructor as well, if your Sequence class gets any more complex.